# How to make a top 5 of array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stored in a value: `$data`
The array's structure is as follows:

```
[0]=>
    array(1447) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "ga:country"
        [1]=>
        string(7) "ga:date"
        [2]=>
        string(11) "ga:sessions"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(11) "Afghanistan"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "20151129"
        [2]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "Algeria"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "20160413"
        [2]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "Angola"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "20160511"
        [2]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "Angola"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "20160524"
        [2]=>
        string(1) "5"
      }
```

The array has 1400 entries and I need to make a top 5 of countries

```
[0]=>
        string(11) "Afghanistan"
```

with highest values:

```
[2]=>
        string(1) "1"
```

The top must also be of the entries from the last 30 days
I tried to achieve that like this:

```
function last30days($data)
        {
        foreach( $data->data[0] as $key => $item ){
          $days = [];
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 30
                ; $i++) {
                $days[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y-m-01') . " -$i days"));
            }
            return $days;  
        }
```

But I don't know how to make the top 5 values of

```
[2]=>
        string(1) "1"
```

. Also tell me please if I have approached the problem properly with that function. Thank you in advance.
So to make it clear I need to make top of `[2]` for every country...in this example Angola has the highest value

```
[2]=>
            string(1) "5"
```

I can reach that value like this:

```
$data->data[0][4][2]
```

And I get `5`
I have to loop through the array for the [2] value of every country and get the 5 highest values and the name of those 5 countries.

Comment: The array code looks `var_dump()`ed. I think a `print_r()` would have been much easier for me to scan.

Comment: "I need to make a top 5 of countries" - Top five based on what criterion exactly?

Comment: As I said based on: [2]=>
        string(11) "ga:sessions"

Comment: `ga:sessions` occurs in your array only once. Sorting by it doesn't make sense. If you want people to help you provide raw array and think about your question again.

Comment: Ok, to make it clear the first part is only the legend of the array, it explains what the first, second and the third entry represents. '[0]=>
        string(10) "ga:country"
        [1]=>
        string(7) "ga:date"
        [2]=>
        string(11) "ga:sessions"

Comment: So i need to make a top of [2]=>
        string(1) "1"

Comment: A top based on the [2] of every country..do you understand now?